# Rails redirect to another controller's show method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

Within the controller of `currency`, I want to redirect to the show method of `prediction`. How can I do this?

```
def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @currency.update(currency_params)
        prediction = @currency.neural_network.predict
        ###redirect to prediction's controller, show method
        ###???
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @currency.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: For prediction's controller show method, you need to have id of prediction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do `redirect_to prediction`
Rails will automatically resolve path for the model.

Answer (score 2):

simply add `redirect_to prediction`

Doing a redirect_to a specific object goes to the show page for that object. Rails knows that `prediction` is an active record object, so it interprets that as knowing you want to go to the show page for the object.

Here's the [docs for redirect_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Redirecting/redirect_to)

> redirect_to(options = {}, response_status = {}) public
>
> Redirects the browser to the target specified in options.